# Is there any LinkedTreeMap implementation in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

is there any `LinkedTreeMap` implementation available in standard JDK or simple standalone library that support both sorting and insertion order? I found [gridsim](http://www.cloudbus.org/gridsim/) that has a `LinkedTreeMap` [implementation](http://www.cloudbus.org/gridsim/doc/api/gridsim/parallel/profile/LinkedTreeMap.html). But seems it is a big library.

**[UPDATE]**

I want a `Map` which sorts elements based on keys which is `Integer` in my case and also gives me two kinds of `Iterator` based on:

1. sorted keys
2. insertion order

Comment: Do you want an ordered map, retaining the insertion order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you see the [`LinkedTreeMap`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap.java) of [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library?

This preserve the insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this free-standing library: http://tech.dolhub.com/Code/LinkedTree

However, note that the author states that the classes performance is not great compared with `TreeMap`.

Comment: I'm the author of the LinkedTree in question. It's not that performance is "not great", only that it is not *quite as good* as TreeMap. But then, it has more to do than TreeMap.

Comment: Your pages says that the ratio is 1:6 for some operations, and 1:1.33 for others.  That is a bit worse than "not quite as good".  And 1:6 qualifies as "not great", IMO.

Comment: True enough. I really should update that post to talk about how that's counter-balanced by key-lookup followed by sequential read operations, for which it's designed, being much faster and much easier.